# Порядок слов с дательным падежом (прямое дополнение / косвенное дополнение)

Tags: дательный-падеж, синтаксис

В русском языке, как правило, косвенное дополнение (в дательном падеже) предшествует прямое дополнение, например, в следующем предложении:

**Я подарила брату чемодан.**

Если меняешь стандартный порядок слов, какой смысловой оттенок будет в предложении? Например:

**Я подарила чемодан брату.**

**Я брату подарила чемодан.**

Как носитель русского языка будет воспринимать эти два предложения?

Значение или подчеркивание имён существительных будет отличаться от стандартного/грамматического предложения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Я подарила брату чемодан.***

This is just you telling someone that you gifted a suitcase to your
brother.

> ***Я подарила чемодан брату.***

Sounds to me more like a start of a full sentence.  E.g.

> *Я подарила чемодан брату, а он его выкинул!*

> ***Брату я подарила чемодан.***

Again, sounds like a beginning of a sentence:

> *Брату я подарила чемодан, а сестре — сумку.*

> ***Я брату подарила чемодан.***

> ***Чемодан я подарила брату.***

Etc.  These sound like you're trying to write a poem, heh.

Answer (score 4):

Change of word order highlights different accents in the meaning. Generally, pulling a word forward from its "normal" place implies that it's for some reason more important.

"Я подарила брату чемодан." - Neutral meaning.

"Я подарила чемодан брату." - "Чемодан" is more important for some reason. Usually, this is implied from the context, like: "А где твой зеленый чемодан?" - "Я подарила чемодан брату."

"Я брату подарила чемодан." - "Брат" is more important than normal. Ex: "А что ты подарила брату на день рождения?" - "Я брату подарила чемодан."